# CodeIgniter's form action is not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, forms, codeigniter-routing

I have failed many times to figure out why the action attribute of my form is malfunctioning when I click the submit button.

All I wanted to do is to pass the form data to the controller. But what's happening is that the browser is just redirecting me to another page (on localhost, even the URI is correctly supplied.)

```
<form name = "employee" method = "post" action = "<?php echo base_url() .'employee/add_employee'; ?>">
First Name:  <input type = "text" name = "F_Name">
Middle Name: <input type = "text" name = "M_Name">
Last Name:   <input type = "text" name = "L_Name">
<input type = "submit" value = "save">
</form>
```

Here's the add_employee function in my employee.php (with the class name of 'Employee'):

```
public function add_employee(){

    $employee = array(
    'F_Name' => $this->input->post('F_Name'),
    'M_Name' => $this->input->post('M_Name'),
    'L_Name' => $this->input->post('L_Name')
    );

    $this->Employee_model->insert_employee($employee);

    echo "Employee added!<br />";
}
```

I don't think the Employee_model is the problem, so I won't add it here. I'm guessing that the problem has to do with the URL in my form action.

Why is the browser redirecting me to another page instead of executing the add_employee() function?

Comment: Why not using the form helper from codeigniter ? What is the other page link ? Do you have an output ? Also, you can access to the $this->input->post from your model.

Comment: Yes, I use `$this->input->post` in  my model. But the problem is that the controller's  function is not reached for some reason.

Comment: Do you have error in your php ? Try to just echo something in the function add_employee.

Comment: No errors found. I am just redirected to the localhost. This is the link in the address bar `http://localhost/CI_Practice2/employee/add_employee`

Comment: `http://localhost/CI_Practice2/employee/add_employee`. I echoed it and it was the result. @Simon But surprisingly, I am  redirected to localhost itself and not as it is defined here.

Comment: If you echo something before the $employee = array, do you have something ??

Comment: Good point, let me try it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29455/discussion-between-simon-and-arman)

Comment: did u try site_url() instead of base_url()? site_url should be used for links and forms, it will add the index.php etc if it configured that way in ur ./application/config/config.php file

Comment: @Simon and @Hashem , I moved from wamp to xampp. The only thing that had changed is there is now an error message telling me that something is wrong (unlike before). So I tried your solutions and found out that Simon is correct, about rewriting `RewriteBase /CI/` into `RewriteBase /CI_Practice2`. That solved my problem. Simon, could you please post your answer here? Thank you both for your help.  Edit: Using  wamp server still doesnt work even I replaced  that line. Maybe it is an older version?

Comment: @Arman I glad to see your issue has been fixed, updating your question (adding the old `.htaccess` file) would be useful to others have similar issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long discussion, here is the solution :

In your htaccess, you had to change

`RewriteBase /CI/` into `RewriteBase /CI_Practice2`

Also, maybe you have to do this with MAMP (Maybe not)

localhost:8080/CI_Practice2

It's if you didn't change the defaults ports of MAMP.

Have a nice day

Comment: Also I remember that I get my WAMP installer about more than a year ago. Updating this may fix the problem I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use site_url()

Try this

```
<form name = "employee" method = "post" action = "<?php echo site_url('employee/add_employee'); ?>">
```