# CodeIgniter Button does not Trigger Action

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been searching through various questions on the site with no luck. The closest I got to an answer, as far as I can tell, was through the following question: [CodeIgniter's form action is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389485/codeigniters-form-action-is-not-working-properly).

The problem is that when I press the login button nothing happens so the action property in the HTML form is not being triggered. I have looked at my routes as well with no luck.

The HTML code is in my view folder and is the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/login">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" type="username" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" required>
                            </div>
                                <a type="submit" id="login-button" style="navy" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller is called pages.php, and it's function, login is the following:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    if ($username != false && $password != false)
    {
        $loginDetails = $this->pages_model->retrieveLoginDetails($username,  $password);

        if ($loginDetails != false)
        {
            if ($loginDetails['username'] == $username && $loginDetails['password'] == $password)
            {
                $this->load->view ('home');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->view();
                echo "details dont match";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->view();
            echo "nothing received from db";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->view();
        echo "no details entered";
    }
}
```

I am only concerned with going to the home page. By calling the view function I am just returning to the login screen. I will adjust the naming appropriately once I can get this to work. The pages model contains the following function to retrieve the login data from the database:

```
public function retrieveLoginDetails ($username, $password)
{
    $loginDetails['username'] = $this->db->get_where('user_details', $username);

    if (! empty ($loginDetails['username']))
    {
        $loginDetails['password'] = $this->db->get_where('user_details', $password);
        return $loginDetails;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `action="<?php echo base_url("index.php/pages/login"); ?>"`

Comment: I have a route as follows `$route ['login'] = 'pages/login';` within the routes.php file in config.

Comment: remove your route for a while and try.

Comment: I have made your changes and no luck. I am unsure if it's possibly the .htaccess file

Comment: Use `<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />` in place of `<a type="submit" ></a>`.

Comment: IT WORKED :D amazing, thank you! Next problem is the database which I will work on now as the output on the page is "nothing received from db"

Comment: If you find any issue while working with database post your question I will help you..

Comment: You're awesome :D haha. Can we move this over to chat? I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Below our comments, when you try add another comment, it says: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?". Hit the hyperlink and hopefully it will begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />
```

In place of

```
<a type="submit" id="login-button" style="navy" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
```

To know more check out this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 1):

I don't know direct anwser, but did you check what exactly is your server returning and where are data beeing sent. LiteBug FTW ;)

If there isn't any data beeing sent, you should probally check your .js files.

Comment: Thanks to @Indrasinh the button now works because of a silly tag problem. The database is not returning anything. I am exploring that now.